# JTable ComboBox loses value when clicked elsewhere

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

I have set a `jCombobox` as `DefaultCellEditor` for a `JTable` cell.

The problem comes when I type a value in the cell (`jCombobox`) and whenever I click somewhere else, the value is lost. Someone knows why and how can I fix this?

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(new SpringJobTablePopupCellEditor());

public class SpringJobTablePopupCellEditor extends AbstractCellEditor implements TableCellEditor {

    JTextField jtf;

    DefaultCellEditor other;
    DefaultCellEditor checkbox;
    private DefaultCellEditor lastSelected;
    JComboBox cbox = null;
    public SpringJobTablePopupCellEditor() {
        jtf = new JTextField();
        jtf.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(1000));

        other = new DefaultCellEditor(jtf);
        checkbox = new DefaultCellEditor(generateBox("10"));
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCellEditorValue() {
        return lastSelected.getCellEditorValue();
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
    final JTable t = table;
    cbox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addFocusListener(new FocusListener() {

        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
            if(t.isEditing()){
                t.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();
            }
        }
    });
        String val = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column - 1).toString();

        if("ak".equals(val)){
            lastSelected = checkbox;
            return checkbox.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
        }
        lastSelected = other;
        return other.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
    }

    private JComboBox generateBox(String type) {

        cbox = new JComboBox();
        cbox.setEditable(true);
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : SpringJob.akMap.entrySet()) {
            cbox.addItem(entry.getValue());
        }
        return cbox;
    }

}
```

Comment: If I recall correctly the default behaviour for a table editor losing focus is to cancel the edit

Comment: Take a look at [Table Stop Editing](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/12/12/table-stop-editing/)

Comment: Also verify your implementation of `setValueAt()`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
JTable table = new yourTable();
table.putClientProperty("terminateEditOnFocusLost", Boolean.TRUE);
```

When you go from one combobox to another you need to force your table to stop editing
i achieved similar with adding a focusListener to the combobox and in the focuslost adding

```
public void focusLost(FocusEvent e) {
    if (table.isEditing())
        table.getCellEditor().stopCellEditing();        
    }
}
```

Comment: didn't work! I put a value in the combo and then click on the cell below, the value of the combo set to default (empty).

Comment: Correct, the table does not loose focus so the extra property does not help.

Comment: Nothing changed for me!

Answer (score 0):

Combo box has stored more than one items list normally. when you click JCombo box in jtable and type the value it will not add directly in to combobox list item. you must add value first in combo-box. Combo-box contains array of objects.

**Try this code its dynamically add value in Jtable combo-box**

```
static JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
static JTable table = new JTable();
public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
    JPanel middlepanel = new JPanel();

    combo.addItem("First");
    combo.addItem("Second");
    combo.addItem("Third");

    JButton button = new JButton("Add Item");
    topPanel.add(button);        
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setSize(500, 500);
    frame.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    model.addColumn("A", new Object[] { "item1" });
    middlepanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    middlepanel.add(table,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    String str[] = new String[combo.getItemCount()];
    for(int i=0;i<combo.getItemCount();i++){
        str[i] = combo.getItemAt(i).toString();
    }
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(combo));
    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer(str));
    table.setRowHeight(25);

    frame.add(middlepanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String cmd = e.getActionCommand();
            switch(cmd)
            {
                case "Add Item":
                    combo.addItem("Fourth");
                    combo.addItem("Fifth");
                    String str[] = new String[combo.getItemCount()];
                    for(int i=0;i<combo.getItemCount();i++){
                        str[i] = combo.getItemAt(i).toString();
                    }
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellEditor(new MyComboBoxEditor(combo));
                    table.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setCellRenderer(new MyComboBoxRenderer(str));
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{

}
```